# Ansible jinja2 template use variable into lookup

Tags: ansible, jinja2

I'm failing to understand how to lookup some hosts in a group.

The inventory file:

```
[mygroup]
www.mysite.com
```

The template:

```
{% for host in groups['mygroup'] %}
{{ lookup('dig', '{{ host }}')}}
{% endfor %}
```

I tried to use also 'host' without {{ }} and I got only blank lines.
Any idea?

Comment: Try to use `host` without `'`: `{{ lookup('dig', host)}}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using nested `{{` which is not acceptable in jinja2.

```
{% for host in groups['mygroup'] %}
{{ lookup('dig', host)}}
{% endfor %}
```